# How can I open a new terminal in the same directory of the last used one from a window manager keybind?

Tags: bash, terminal, cd-command, rxvt

I'm using a tiling window manager and I switched from `gnome-terminal` with multiple tabs to multiple `urxvt` instances managed by the window manager. One of the features I miss is the ability to open a new terminal that defaults to the working directory of the last one.

In short: **I need a way to open a new urxvt (bash) that defaults to $PWD of the last used one.**

The only solution that comes to my mind is to save the current path on every `cd` with something like this:

```
echo $PWD > ~/.last_dir
```

and restore the path on the new terminal in this way:

```
cd `cat ~/.last_dir`
```

I can source the second command in `.bashrc` but I don't know how to execute the first one on every directory change :)

Any simpler solution that does not involve `screen` or `tmux` usage is welcome.

Comment: Are you using the "`tabbed`" perl extension of `urxvt`?

Comment: No tabs, I'm using new terminals managed by WM

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I see three solutions using `.last_dir`. You can place the `echo $PWD > ~/.last_dir` either:

1. In a special function that would be a wrapper for `cd`:

   ```
   function cd_
   {
     [[ -d "$@" ]] || return 1
     echo "$@" > ~/.last_dir
     cd "$@"
   }
   ```

   Place this in your `~/.bashrc` and then use `cd_` instead of cd every time you want your new working directory to be stored.
2. In your `$PROMPT_COMMAND` (*not recommended*):

   ```
   PROMPT_COMMAND="$PROMPT_COMMAND; pwd > ~/.last_dir"
   ```

   You can test this directly from the terminal or place it in `~/.bashrc`. This solution, however, triggers a disk write each time the prompt appears, which might cause trouble - but on the other hand, `.last_dir` would contain the current directory no matter how you got there.
3. In a custom *perl extension script* for `rxvt`. I've never created one myself, but you can find quite a few examples on the web.

Comment: PROMPT_COMMAND that's what I was looking for. I will try this solution hoping it doesn't affect performances.

Comment: Well, it is a rather crude way, frankly. Personally, I like Michael's solution best :)

Comment: I like the perl extension way, if it needs to work outside of the terminal; it seems cleaner than hacking something into `PROMPT_COMMAND`, one of the most abused environment variables of all time

Comment: It seems that $PWD is evaluated only the first time

Comment: @neon Aaah... Sorry. The problem is with with how the PROMPT_COMMAND is quoted. (Or rather, how `$PWD` was *not* quoted.) Let me fix this... There. That ought to do it.

Comment: Thank you! There is a side effect of this solution, it remains after reboot/logout :) In my case is not a security issue but a nice feature.

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-terminal/+bug/1132700

For gnome-terminal just do: `. /etc/profile.d/vte.sh`

Answer (score 17):

I'm currently using this version of #1 solution

```
# save path on cd
function cd {
    builtin cd $@
    pwd > ~/.last_dir
}

# restore last saved path
if [ -f ~/.last_dir ]
    then cd `cat ~/.last_dir`
fi
```

inside my `.zshrc`

Comment: i'm using #1 solution too and add `trap "[ -f ~/.last_dir ] && rm ~/.last_dir" EXIT` i want start always in my home except when i open a new tab

Comment: This doesn't work if using the `auto_cd` feature of zsh. It turns out we can use  a hook that zsh provides: https://gist.github.com/jonleighton/1f0b96b49247a07dbaa30fbbe70b34f7

Answer (score 13):

This is actually pretty trivial; if you run `urxvt` from within your existing `urxvt` window, the new window will be in the same directory. I have `dup` aliased to `urxvt &` for this reason. If you want it bound to a hotkey, you can use bash's `bind` command. For example, to bind it to <kbd>F1</kbd>:

```
$ bind '"\e[11~": "urxvt &\n"'
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I knew that terminal child processes maintained the state but I didn't know that you can bind a key to a command in bash. I'd like to do this from WM to avoid focusing the terminal.

Comment: I like that. No disk writes and the only execution takes place when you're about to open the new terminal.

Comment: The only thing I'd change is to use `( urxvt & ) &>/dev/null` instead of just backgrounding.

Comment: This solution is great and more flexible but I don't like to use 2 bindings, one to launch the terminal and one to fork a new one.

Answer (score 7):

Just add `. /etc/profile.d/vte.sh` in your `~/.bashrc` to get the same feature

Comment: This work, however, why bother -1 this?

Comment: This works, and it looks like it's actually the preferred solution on launchpad / of gnome-terminal devs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-terminal/+bug/1132700

Comment: And you have to put it before and hypothetical `PS1` modification. Here is a more "official" justification : https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Terminal/FAQ

Answer (score 4):

Of course it is a working approach to modify `cd`'s behavior, but I would like to show a more simple solution. In the [man bash(1)](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Startup-Files) I found that if an interactive [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) exits it runs `~/.bash_logout` if exists. So instead of storing the path at every invocation of `cd` the last path can be saved at exit.

My `~/.bash_logout` is very simple:

```
echo $PWD >~/.lastdir
```

And somewhere in my `.bashrc` I placed this line:

```
[ -r ~/.lastdir ] && cd $(<~/.lastdir)
```

Comment: Just note that `.bash_logout` runs only when `login shells` exit, that's not always the case.

Comment: Alternatively, save the last path when `bash` exits with :  `trap "echo $PWD > ~/.lastdir" EXIT"`

Comment: @henfiber Thanks for your comments! I think in this case the shell is a login shell, so this will behave properly. On the other hand the `trap` approach is also nice, I like it!

Answer (score 2):

Very often I use multiple terminal windows at once, each with multiple tabs in it. For example: one window for source code development tabs, one window for latex files, one window for R execution and scripting, etc.
Within one window, I want a new tabbed terminal  to change to the directory which is used last in that particular window (this used to work in the past, but with the new gnome version, somehow it doesn't). The following dirty solution works fine for me. I have put this in .bashrc.

```
dirfilename="/tmp/.lastdir-$WINDOWID"
[ -r "$dirfilename" ] &&  {
    savdir=`cat $dirfilename`
    cd "$savdir"
}

function cd ()
{
    builtin cd "$@"
    echo $PWD > $dirfilename
}
```

Comment: This is perfect... wohoo! Thanks. I don't know a lot about hacking bash, but man I'm already loving it...

Answer (score 0):

In zsh, you can use the hooks:

```
chpwd_functions=(${chpwd_functions[@]} "function-that-saves-pwd")
```

Answer (score -1):

Paste this on ~/.bashrc, (or ~/.zshrc if you use zsh).

```
set_working_dir() {
  # All terminals after this command, will be opened in your current directory.
  for var in "$@"
  do
    echo "$var" > ~/.cache/.last_dir 
  done
    if [ $# -eq 0 ]
  then
    pwd > ~/.cache/.last_dir
    fi
  echo '* Working directory saved.'
}
alias sdw='set_working_dir'
```

Reboot, and you can use it like:

```
swd
```

or

```
swd "/some/directory"
```

Then launch your terminal like:

```
nameofyourterminal --working-directory=$(cat ~/.cache/.last_dir)
```

Comment: Reboot ? I think there is a lighter alternative like sourcing the resource file again. And I'm not speaking about the fact this script seems to mimic a native behavior in a none working way.